# How can i open editor from context menu?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have created one context menu in Eclipse.I want to open an Editor after clicking on it?
How can i open editor from context menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_RCP_How-to#Editor) you find some short examples. Maybe that is enough to give you an idea...

```
 IWorkbenchPage page;
 IEditorInput input;
 page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench ().getActiveWorkbenchWindow ().getActivePage ();
 // else if in ViewPart // page = getSite ().getPage ();
 page.openEditor (input, "editor_id");
```